# power series and measure theory

Tags: measure-theory

I am reading Rudins book "Complex analysis", and I have problem with the following.

Suppose that sequence $\lbrace a_{ij}\rbrace_{i, j = 1}^{\infty}$ is given, and $a_{i j}\ge 0$. Proof, that

$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}a_{ij} = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_{ij}$.

I am trying to do it using this

**THEOREM**

Suppose, that $f_n\colon X\to [0,\infty]$ is measurable for $n=1,2,3\ldots$ and $f = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n$. Then

$\int_X f d\mu = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_Xf_n d\mu$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $f_j:\mathbb N\to[0,\infty]$ be given by $f_j(i)=a_{ij}$. It is measurable, because you can take the discrete topology on $\mathbb N$. Then
$$
\sum_{i=1}^\infty\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_{ij}
=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\sum_{j=1}^\infty f_j(i)=\int_{\mathbb N} \sum_{j=1}^\infty f_j
=\sum_{j=1}^\infty \int_{\mathbb N}f_j
=\sum_{j=1}^\infty\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_{ij}
$$